# Kullback-Leibler Divergence between a random variable and the product of its entries

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, random-graphs

### Problem Statement

I'm currently working with a result about Kullback-Leibler divergence. Let $X$ be an discrete random variable taking values in $\mathcal{X} := \{0,1\}^p$, with $X = (X_1, X_2,...,X_p)$. Suppose that the distribution of X and its components $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^p$ are $g_X$ and $\{g_{X_i}\}_{i=1}^p$ respectively, then show that:
$$
KL(g_X||\prod_{i=1}^pg_{X_i}) = \sum_{i=1}^nH(X_i)-H(X)
$$

### My Proof Attempt

$$
KL(g_X||\prod_{i=1}^pg_{X_i}) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} g_X(x)\log\left(\frac{g_X(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^pg_{X_i}(x)}\right)
$$
$$
= -H(X)-\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}g_X(x)\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^pg_{X_i}(x)\right)
$$
$$
= -H(X)-\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}g_X(x)\sum_{i=1}^p\log(g_{X_i}(x))
$$
$$
= -H(X)-\sum_{i=1}^pg_X(x)\log(g_{X_i}(x))
$$
Now here is the step I have a problem with... Can I say that $\sum_{i=1}^pg_X(x)\log(g_{X_i}(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^pH(X_i)$? This feels like it should require independence, but the notes I'm working through do not make such assumption. Maybe I've done something wrong before this step?

### Further Comments

If the result holds, does anybody know a way to upper bound this? In context, the $X_i$ follow a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p(R_i)$, where the $R_i$ are identically (but not independently) distributed $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables. In my application the $X_i$ represent the existence of edges in a random geometric graph, and $R_i$ represent distances between randomly distributed points (to explain why they are not independent).

Comment: You're almost there, I think it is just a matter of clearly writing it. $$\sum_{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p) \in \mathcal{X}} \sum_{i =1}^p g_X(x) \log(g_{X_i}(x_i)) = \sum_{i =1}^p  \log(g_{X_i}(x_i)) \sum_{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p) \in \mathcal{X}}  g_X(x) = \sum_{i =1}^p  \sum_{x_i \in \{0,1\}} \log(g_{X_i}(x_i)) g_{X_i}(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^p H(X_i)$$. The third step is marginalization.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Ah yes thank you! I see that now.